# Different cscopequickfix behavior for vimrc and command line

Tags: vim, cscope

If I do `set cscopequickfix=g-` in my `vimrc` file, it does not work: search results do not get listed in quick fix window.
But if I do `:set cscopequickfix=g-` from `vim` command line, it starts working as expected.
What's even more puzzling to me, is that `g` search is the only one that this happens to. The rest of them `e-`, `s-`, etc... if I put `set cscopequickfix=e-,s-,` in my `vimrc` file, search results for them get directed to quick fix window correctly.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It works for me. Try to bisect your configuration.

Comment: I know it is a silly question, but did you reload your vimrc file after each change? (`:source $MYVIMRC`)

Comment: mMontu, yes, I was reloading my vimrc file when I was making the changes to the cscopequickfix setting, and it worked as if I ran :set cscopequickfix=... from the command line. It's when I restart vim is when I don't see cscope working correctly with quickfix. If I do a re-source or run a 'set' from the command line, then 'g-' part starts working correctly...

Comment: I found cscopequickfix should not be set, if set the quickfix window never show. I use cscope.vim(https://github.com/vim-scripts/cscope.vim) and pycscope, they set cscopequickfix for me, and i need to unset it. After unset, all are ok.